# Slow loading data highstock

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have trouble with performance of my highstock. All works, but time of plotting of my data is too slow, about 30 seconds. JSON is about 30000 points. Maybe problem in how  I draw this data ? I already turn off animation, shadow, marks etc.

[image]

And here is my JS code:

```
$(function() {
    Highcharts.setOptions({
        global: {
useUTC: false,
            timezoneOffset: - 3 * 60
        }
    });
function requestData() {
$.ajax({
    url: 'values.php',
    success: function(series) {
        chart.addSeries({name: 'Temp1', data: series[0], yAxis:0},       false);
        chart.addSeries({name: 'Temp2', data: series[1], yAxis:0}, false);  
        chart.redraw();
    },
    cache: false
});
}
chart = new Highcharts.StockChart({
    chart: {
    animation: false,
        zoomType: 'xy',
        renderTo: 'container',
        events: {
            load: requestData
        }
    },
title: {
            text: 'Temperatures from DS18B20',
            x: -20 
        },                  
plotOptions: {
                    spline: {
                        turboThreshold: 50000
                    }
                },
rangeSelector: {
allButtonsEnabled: true,
buttons: [{
type: 'minute',
count: 10,
text: '10min'
}, {
type: 'minute',
count: 30,
text: '30min'
}, {
type: 'all',
text: 'all'
}],
buttonTheme: {
width:60
     },
selected: 2
},


 xAxis: {
   type: 'datetime',
   categories: true,
   ordinal: false,
    //   tickInterval: 100*3600,
   minTickInterval:100000,
   labels: {
     align: 'center',
          formatter:function(){
     return Highcharts.dateFormat('%H:%M:%S',this.value);
     }
   }
 },
    yAxis: {
        labels: {
            format: '{value}°C',
            style: {
                color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0]
            }
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Temperature',
            style: {
                color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0]
            }
        },
        opposite: false
    },
    legend: {
        enabled: true,
        align: 'right',
        backgroundColor: '#DBFFDB',
        borderColor: 'black',
        borderWidth: 2,
        layout: 'vertical',
        verticalAlign: 'top',
        y: 200,
        shadow: true
    },

    tooltip: {
        shared: true
    },
    series: []
});
});
```

Comment: Do you have sorted data by x ascending? Can you attach your JSON with data, because this it not too many points.

Comment: @Sebastian Bochan
JSON is 2 big arrays for 2 sensors, each array include about 10000 arrays, which looks like {time,value}.
So format is [{time,value1},{time,value2}],[{time,value1},{time,value2}]
I attach picture with part of JSON
![JSON_IMG](http://i.imgur.com/pZdbKDs.png).

Comment: Specifically JSON is 
`$temp[]= array((int)strtotime($row['time']) * 1000,(float)$row['value']);
$temp1[]= array((int)strtotime($row['time']) * 1000,(float)$row['value1']);
$temp0= array($temp,$temp1);
echo json_encode($temp0);`

Comment: Can you send me this output json? It will allow me tro replicate the issue, because from the picture, is not possible.

Comment: @SebastianBochan Ok, check this
https://jsfiddle.net/62vd9qea/

Comment: Well, I have no access to your database, can you hardcode these values ?

Comment: @SebastianBochan Okey, try this
https://dropmefiles.com/uydMO

Comment: I recreated your chart as demo: https://jsfiddle.net/cobses8w/ The performance issues seems to not appear. Please check how long your ajax takes, because it looks like a problem with time loading data from back-end not chart init.

Comment: @SebastianBochan If I understood right, ajax time is 42 sec. And I don't know what to do..

Comment: It looks that the border is communication / network efficient. Physical problem not related with the software.

Comment: @SebastianBochan Maybe problem because redraw chart each point in Ajax block or I understood wrong ?

Comment: You redraw only one time. I set the timers and chart is printed in more or less two seconds (with hardcoded values). Run the developer tools (i.e Chrome) and in Network tab, check how long loading AJAX takes you.

Comment: @SebastianBochan It seems that's what you told me, but how can I fix it?
[TIMING](https://i.imgur.com/C7mNhQG.jpg)

Comment: Being honest, if your server responses 42s, it is a problem with the network or server incorrect configuration. So Im not sure what you can do more.